# bcrypt.compareSync sempre retornando falso

Tags: node.js, rest, bcrypt

Estou criando uma api por motivos de estudos, e estou com um problema que o bcrypt fica retornando false pelo que me parece, eu usei essa mesma função de comparação em outro projeto de estudos e tinha funcionado. O que posso estar fazendo de errado para a comparação não funcionar como deveria? Dei até uma lida na documentação e acredito estar fazendo certo.

Estou criando o meu usuario dessa forma:

```
router.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password

    try {

        await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } }).then(user => {
            if (user == undefined) {
                let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)

                User.create({
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    password: hash
                })
                res.sendStatus(201)
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(400)
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

E esta é a roda de autenticação que estou tentando validar o usuário

router.post("/auth", async (req, res) => {

```
var { email, password } = req.body

if (email != undefined) {

    var user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } })

    if (user != undefined) {
        
        var correct = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)

        if (req.body.password == correct) {

            res.status(200)
            res.json({ token: "Token falso" })
        } else {
            res.status(401)
            res.json({ err: "credenciais inválidas" })
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404)
        res.json({ err: "O email enviado não existe" })
    }
} else {
    res.status(400)
    res.json({ err: "O email enviado é inválido" })
}
```

})

Comment: esse `if (req.body.password == correct){...}` nao deveria ser `if (correct){...}`? poque do jeito que voce escreveu, voce ta comparando uma string qualquer (`req.body.password`) com um boolean (`correct`), logo vai ser sempre `false` e nao vai retornar o `status(200)` nunca

Comment: Puts cara, era exatamente isso. vlw ai man, de verdade, como eu fecho a pergunta?